# Can I disable the remote attribute to check for duplicates when editing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a typical CRUD scenario, if the table has a code for the primary key rather than an id, I add the remote attribute to the model to check for duplicates when creating a record.

The problem I have is that the same model is used when editing a record, which forces the same duplicate validation check, and even if I remove the ValidationMsgFor in the Edit.cshtml for the code, save doesn't work due to the attribute being added to the model.

If I remove the remote attribute, then it works (but create doesn't check for duplicates). I don't want to have two models, that feels really messy.

Does anybody know any alternatives apart from manually doing an Ajax call to validate? I.e. can I disable the remote attribute when editing?

Thanks for reading.

Example code:

In the Department model (DepartmentCode is the primary key on the table, i.e. there is no integer id):

```
...
[Remote("DuplicateCheck", "Department", ErrorMessage = "Duplicate Found", HttpMethod="Post")]
[Display(Name = "Department Code")]
public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
...
```

In the Department controller:

```
...
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DuplicateCheck(string departmentCode)
{       
    return Json(!_departmentRepository.Exists(departmentCode));
}
...
```

In the view (this could be create or edit):

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DepartmentCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: You dont disable it (you still need to check if its a duplicate) You pass the ID to the method as `AdditionalFields`. If its `null` (or zero) you know its a new object, otherwise its an existing object so you exclude the existing value

Comment: Many thanks, I'd got into doing manual validation rather than thinking about the additional parameters. This suggestion means I have a pointless Ajax call when editing but its a major improvement on having two models.

Comment: I've noticed this question has been marked down, please could whoever marked it down comment as to why, so I can improve either this question or for the future??

Comment: You have not given enough information to add an answer - what is the property you apply it to and what is the ID property of the model, and what is the current code the controller that `RemoteAttribute` calls? (note I did not down vote but I'm considering it because of the lack of code)

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll remember what you have said there... And better quickly add some code to the question... :-)

Comment: I'm guessing now from the code, that this is a data model and not a view model? (a `RemoteAttribute` is a view specific attribute (as is `DisplayAttribute`) and should not be applied to a data model.

Comment: So far in this app (this question relates to the first page), I havn't made a distinction between the two - I tend to make VIewModel's in the MVC model folder when needed. I think you are right though, this is a reason to have a ViewModel, or I could do manual validation in the view and leave the model clean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114515/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-philip-johnson).